# problem with packing buttons in LabelFrame in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

the buttons should be packed in the LabelFrame but they don't
they are packed in the root screen

the Code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('300x300')

frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Hello')
frame.pack(expand='yes', fill='both', padx=10, pady=10)

btn1 = tk.Button(frame, text='Button 1').pack()
btn2 = tk.Button(frame, text='Button 2').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How did you know they are packed in the root window?  Your code looks fine.

Comment: Your buttons _are_ being packed in the LabelFrame. Why do you think they are not?

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not causing the problem you have mentioned, just be careful that .pack() should not be used inline when you are assigning the btn1, btn2 variables to Button object. Here is the modified code -

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry('300x300')

frame = tk.LabelFrame(root, text='Hello')
frame.pack(expand='yes', fill='both', padx=10, pady=10)

btn1 = tk.Button(frame, text='Button 1')
btn1.pack()
btn2 = tk.Button(frame, text='Button 2')
btn2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What what you wrote is true, it's not preventing the buttons from being inside the labelframe.